# WebDriverManager for PhantomJSDriver not working

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I cannot get [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) to work. I would like to use PhantomJSDriver without having to set a system property like this:

```
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "E:/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");
```

I have these dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my code/test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestA {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass() {
        PhantomJsDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        driver.get("https://www.google.de/");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        assertEquals("Google", driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

The test fails:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[Google]> but was:<[]>
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE:** Now I have another problem. Before using the webdrivermanager I had this:

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
dc.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
dc.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS,
                new String[] { "--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes" });

System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "E:/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dc);
```

Now, when I delete the line with `System.setProperty(...)`, it is not working anymore. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Check that it actually downloaded the PhantomJS binary. From it's code I see it generates logs. Attach them to the question or use them to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your making the assertion to early, so the page is not loaded when you call getTitle() on it. What does your println print out?

Try adding a wait to to your test, if you know the page title should be "Google" then why not wait for that to be true before doing any further assertions? When the page title is equal to what your expecting you can be reasonably confident the page is loaded. Try this:

```
public Boolean waitForPageIsLoaded(String title) {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs(title));
}
```

Comment: For some reason I thought the same test would work with FirefoxDriver but it is actually not. Your answer is working for me, thanks!

Comment: I have another problem now, I updated my question. Maybe you could also answer it?

Comment: Ask a new question

Comment: I will ask the new question next week. I have other stuff to do right now at work. This helped so far, though! Thanks